# Saving 3 schema simultaneously in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I'm trying to save in 3 schema (User, UserDetail and Team) data in mongo DB simultaneously but I receive an error

(node:14432) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Here's my code

```
self.createTeam = function (req, res) {
    Logger.request(req);
    Logger.requestBody(req);

    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, function (err, hash) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: err
            })

        } else {

            req.body.password = hash;

            const team = new Teams({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                domain: req.body.domain,
                avatarOriginal: req.body.avatarOriginal,
                avatar_180x180: req.body.avatar_180x180,
                avatar_180x100: req.body.avatar_180x100,
                name: req.body.name,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                updatedAt: Date.now()
            });
    
            const user = new User({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                username: req.body.username,
                email: req.body.email,
                password: hash,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                updatedAt: Date.now()
            });
    
            const userDetail = new UserDetail({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                user_id: user._id,
                team_id: team._id,
                firstName: req.body.firstName,
                lastName: req.body.lastName,
                createdAt: Date.now(),
                updatedAt: Date.now()
            })


            team.save().then(function (result) {
                return user.save();
            }).then(function (result) {
                return userDetail.save();
            }, function (err) {
                res.status(500).json({
                    error: err
                });
            }).then(function (user) {
                
                Logger.response(req, user);

                res.status(200).json({
                    success: 'New team and user has been created'
                })
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Please help thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NodeJs UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error \[ERR\_HTTP\_HEADERS\_SENT\]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856532/nodejs-unhandledpromiserejectionwarning-error-err-http-headers-sent-cannot-s)

Comment: I already solved my problem. Thanks btw.